# How can I use something stored in a DataBase? SQLite / Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

So, I am new at DataBases and I have a question. I first made a re-search in the internet but could not find anything or actually I could not understand correctly what they were explaining. Before starting with my question I want to say that I am currently working in a Discord Bot in Python as Main Language and I am trying to create a `per-server-prefix` system. I have already made it once but in `.JSON` format. Then I heard that using `.JSON` to save this kind of Data is not actually good so I moved to DataBases. Now, my question is:

I have stored the `guild_id` and `prefix` in my DB, how could I use that for a `per-server-prefix` system? I have not tried anything yet except writing the Code to store both Texts. I would really love if anyone could explain to me not just tell me the Code! Any answer will be appreciated <3.

**Main.py:**

```
def get_prefix(client, message):

    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM prefixes WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        return "/"
    else:
        

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix)
```

**Prefixes.py (COGS):**

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix=None):

        db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT prefix FROM prefixes WHERE guild_id = ?", ctx.guild.id)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            sql = ("INSERT INTO prefixes(guild_id, prefix) VALUES(?,?)")
            val = (ctx.guild.id, prefix)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{prefix}")
        elif result is not None:
            sql = ("UPDATE prefixes SET prefix = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
            val = (prefix, ctx.guild.id)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"update `{prefix}`")
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

That is pretty much the whole code. If you think anything should be changed or have any suggestions, answer in the comments!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. As far as I can tell, your code should work. All you need to do is return the `result` after the `else` clause.

Comment: That's the point, I do not know what the `else` will be. As I said, I'm new at DataBases and I'm still learning. So I'm asking if anyone knows how the `else` will work.

Comment: Ahhhh. In that case, I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is, after the `else`, put `return result`. For example:

```py
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result is None:
    return "/"
else:
    return result
```

`cursor.fetchone()` returns a tuple with each element requested in the row, as you only requested the prefix, it will contain just that (e.g: `("!",)`) which is permitted as your `command_prefix` callable can return a string or tuple of strings.

**Warning:**
You may want to add a check to ensure that someone doesn't specify an empty string (A zero length string with nothing in it) as their prefix, otherwise your bot will attempt to run every message it sees as a command

References: [discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command_prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

Comment: Damn I feel stupid now, that was a bit easy to be honest. Anyways thank you for the answer. Also about the `Warning`, what you are saying is that I should put an error for everyone that set's `""` for a prefix?

Comment: I used `""` to show an empty string (e.g: nothing within it). Just check that the length of the prefix someone sets is greater than zero.

Comment: Oh alright alright! I see. I'll try right now the code and I will tell you if it works!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your coding adventures!

Comment: else is redundant. You can just do `return result` at the end of the function

Comment: @AlexKim You're right, `else` is redundant. But from a beginner perspective, it is much easier to understand the code flow than a random return. There is also little to no difference in performance.